# How can I create a menustrip with multi content?

Tags: c#, winforms, menu, custom-controls

I want to create a custom menustrip (so that it can change the menu content).
My idea is that I set three properties: v1, v2, lang1. v1 is menustrip text for content 1, v2 is for content 2. lang is an integer which determines the content.
Such as below:

```
public string settext1 {get {return text1;} set {text1=value}; }
public int Lang {get {return lang1;} set {lang1=value};if (lang==1)menustrip.text=text1;if(lang==2)menustrip.text=text2; }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about not creating a custom one, but using the [`Tag` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) to store your own object?

The `Tag` property is of type `object` and common to all `Control`-derived classes. You could e.g. create your own class and add it then to the property.

```
public class MyTagInfo
{
    public string V1 { get; set; }
    public string V2 { get; set; }
    public int Lang { get; set; }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
menustrip.Tag = new MyTagInfo { V1 = "...", V2 = "...", Lang = 1 };
```

Comment: Without more info then than that given in the question, this is an intelligent answer.

Comment: how t use menustrip.Tag? I am not quite understand

Answer (score 0):

You could have separate controls in the menustrip, one for each `Lang` value. Then, whenever `Lang` changes, you could re-set the `Enabled` or `Visible` property of the controls.

You could/should do that in the `Lang` setter, so you can be sure that every Lang change will configure your GUI appropriately.